# Are any English versions of the Bible suspect according to Lutheranism?

Tags: bible-translation, lutheranism

Do Lutherans officially warn about *any* Bible translation?

Comment: Do you mean like the NIVI was canceled by great resistance to the genderless rendition of male pronouns?

Comment: Trent condemned Protestant vernacular translations; Protestants have a very low opinion of non-Protestant ones; the Orthodox are suspicious of both, along with modern, scholarly, or liberal ones, while the latter regard all traditional ones as deeply biased; etc.